# NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How to handle `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` error occuring `atmanagedObjectContext save:&error`.

Comment: what is the error Kindly describe more details

Comment: NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2015-03-31 13:16:12.406 NPG[2310:36260] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

Comment: Are you performing save operation on background thread ? or you have specify your context concurrency type to nsconcurrencytypeprivate ?

Comment: We are performing save operation on background thread

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
or using concurrencytypemainqueue

```
//asyncrhonous

[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
//do stuff with the context
}];

//syncrhonous
[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
//do stuff with the context
}];
```

Comment: This solution is not working in my case. Any other alternate solution?